# Scala Slick 3 how can I make it use threads in the system

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am new to using Slick 3.0 and was wondering how can I set the thread count to equal system available threads? For instance in all of the examples I have seen **numThreads=10** . If I add more CPU's to the system then I will have available more threads; how can I make it so that the increase thread count gets used in Slick 3.0 and not be a hard fixed number like 10 ?

```
database {
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    databaseName = "dbname"
    user = "postgres"
    password = "password"
  }
  numThreads = 10

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Config.withValue("database.numThreads", desiredNumber)`](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/b0ae5cac203ab24f8fd4a04b211b92e479e39490/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/Config.java#L1063) method.